# Splitting a string based on an integer followed by a space

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, split, integer

I have a file full of codes and descriptions.

```
020304 Head, Floor Space
```

I need to split this up into a c# dictionary.  However, I'm just trying to split the string into two parts, the digits and the characters.  So, what I want is following:

```
020304
Head, Floor Space
```

I cannot split based on a space, or any other common delimiter.  I cannot change the file to add a specific delimiter, so I have to work with what I have.  I've tried several ways of splitting this up, but to no avail.  I can get it split based on spaces, but I cannot figure out a way to split it based on an int(digit) followed by a space.

I can only split based upon the number of digits in the int followed by a space, or an int followed by a space.  That is the only way I can think of how to split this string.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could split this up into the needed format?  Thank you

Comment: Make a regular expression, and the split via [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does the number always comes first? I mean at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Yes, the number always comes first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. Most common way is to use "Regular Expression".

Given that number always comes in the beginning you can just use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes `count` as parameter. It will limit the number of elements.

```
string str = "020304 Head, Floor Space";
string[] result = str.Split(new string[]{" "}, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

result array will have

```
020304
Head, Floor Space
```

Comment: I don't get it. The poster said he “cannot split based on a space”, then accepted an answer that splits based on a space.

Comment: @DourHighArch Probably because OP would have tried a overload of `Split` which doesn't takes `count` parameter. Which means that his result will be `020304`, `Head,`, `Floor` and `Space` will be split to `4` elements and not `2` which is what OP wants. My answer addresses this and produces expected output. Is that clear?

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "020304 Head, Floor Space";
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"[0-9]\s"); //digit(s) followed by whitespace
```

.

```
"020304"
"Head, Floor Space"
```

Comment: This works so long as the OP is reading one line in at a time, otherwise you need to split on newline as well (`@"\d\s|\n"`)

Comment: That was my impression but thank you for addition. Same applies to accepted answer, too :) ?